# Expo and react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to integrate Firebase into my expo app using the [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) framework which has several advantages over the regular `firebase` package when it comes to react-native apps.

However, I'm running into difficulties since the [instructions](https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/installation-ios) say I must add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to `ios/[YOUR APP NAME]/GoogleService-Info.plist`, and expo apps don't have an ios folder from what I understand.

Am I pretty much screwed or is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

As the react-native-firebase documentation says, you need to eject your app if you want to use this library with expo. Be mind that eject action is not reversible. More info [here](https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/faq/expo) and [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) and [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html).

> If you use Expo and would like to use this package, you'll need to
>   eject. If you do not want to eject, but wish to make use of features
>   such as Realtime Database (without offline support) & Authentication,
>   you can still use the Firebase Web SDK in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Today, you can't have the Firebase react-native sdk with expo. And this is not planned according to: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/full-native-firebase-integration.

So you have to play only with the javascript sdk from Firebase.

Cloud Firestore is new, it will be better for the javascript sdk for offline and sync.

Comment: I know! I needed it too.

Comment: So what am I giving up by using the regular firebase sdk? Performance, offline, and what else?

Comment: check here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase.

But that Firestore, offline, performance will change with the new Cloud Firestore

Comment: Do you know how annoying it is to develop once you've ejected? Is it pretty much the same or is it way more cumbersome?

Comment: I haven't tried. Expo is very usefull so i'm working with the javascript sdk. And if you want to eject, you can directly go to other starterkit like  https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

Answer (score 2):

The author of this thread: [Fresh Detached Expo + RNFirebase not running on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631438/fresh-detached-expo-rnfirebase-not-running-on-android) has managed to get it working with the `Detached ExpoKit` - so it's not a full ejection and keeps the expo features.

I have asked for the steps he took so we can see about getting something added to our docs and possibly a Detached ExpoKit version of our [starter app.](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter)

See the [expokit detaching docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html) for information about ExpoKit.

Answer (score 2):

It's in progress --

https://blog.expo.io/using-firebase-in-expo-e13844061832

Using Firebase in Expo
And how we plan on adding it to the client 
We are super excited to announce that we will be rolling out a suite of Unimodules that will provide you with easy access to native Firebase features! initially you will only be able to use these in a detached ExpoKit App. But **over time we will be working to add these to vanilla Expo**.

**TL;DR**
Here are the modules, **you will need to detach to add them for now**:

- App/Core
- Analytics
- Authentication
- Cloud Firestore
- Cloud Functions
- Instance ID
- Performance Monitor
- Realtime Database
- Cloud Storage
- Remote Config
- Firebase Cloud Messaging
- Remote Notifications
- Dynamic Linking
- Invites
- Crashlytics

**Also TL;DR**
Here is a boilerplate: https://github.com/EvanBacon/expo-native-firebase

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes.  The 2 top answers state that this is impossible and work isn't planned but a new blog post says this capability will be coming out soon.

Comment: The blog post linked here has been updated with a comment that the planned integration of Expo and react-native-firebase isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 02-12-2021**

Guys expo's **eas-build** is now public. You can add custom native codes and use react-native-firebase. Here is the link to a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=658s) tutorial. The video is short and super easy to follow. Here is the  [link to the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/)

**Previous answer**

If you are using **Firebase** using the mobile configuration, it does not work, but it worked smoothly when I tried the web configuration. Here is the [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/id0Im72UN6w). Watch from `38:20` to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a working set of react-native with redux, firestore and expo. See [Code example](https://github.com/matthiaw/react-native-redux-example/blob/d91d38adb2f376dc3a22825482668de3ad8ccf63/src/Components/roles2.js) at [Github](https://github.com/matthiaw/react-native-redux-example/tree/d91d38adb2f376dc3a22825482668de3ad8ccf63).

But it costs the offline-persistence (see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/436). So from my point of view it costs performance, because i need to be online to get a full working app with firestore and react-native.