# React native build getting failed :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: react-native

I am getting error while building react-native app using command `react-native run-android`

**Error**

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzav;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzav;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

**Failure**

Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong**

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Dependencies in android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: share your app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

delete  `android/app/build` dir 
This work for me.

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [on this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46635170/7406582), you have to compile everything yourself. Add this in your `android/app/build.gradle`.

I don't know if you have the exact same problem, but everytime I ran in dex problems, this was the solution.

```
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.4.2"
```

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea